# open, write into new file, change into words

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes a name of a file.  It should open the file, read it, then write it into a file I call converted.txt with this modification:  Every occurrence of a digit in the file should be replaced with the digit spelled out in caps.  ex. - if given in the first file "3 plus 4 is equal to 7" the new file "converted.txt" would spell out "THREE plus FOUR is equal to SEVEN".  The only numbers I need to worry about are between 0 and 9.  I have multiple questions.  Do I create the file called converted.txt and try to copy from the first file.  If so how do I do that?  And how do I change it to words in the new file

Here is my code so far:

```
def numbers(fileName):
    file = open(fileName, "r")
    file2 = "converted.txt"
    newFile = open(File2, "w")
    for element in file:
        if element == 0:
            element = "ZERO"
        elif element == 1:
            element = "ONE"
        elif element == 2:
            element = "TWO"
        elif element == 3:
            element = "THREE"
        elif element == 4:
            element = "FOUR"
        elif element == 5:
            element = "FIVE"
        elif element == 6:
            element = "SIX"
        elif element == 7:
            element = "SEVEN"
        elif element == 8:
            element = "EIGHT"
        elif element == 9:
            element = "NINE"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only part you're *missing* is the part that writes each element to the `newFile`:

```
newFile.write(element)
```

---

However, there are some things you've gotten *wrong*, as well.

First, each line is a string of multiple words, followed by a newline. So, it's not going to ever be `"0"`. You probably want to split the line into words or characters or something, rather than searching the line as a whole. To split into words, look at the `split` method on strings. To split into characters, just loop over the string.

Second, the string `"0"` and the number `0` are different values in Python. *No* string will ever be `== 0`.

Third, if you `open` a file for writing, and never `close` it, you may end up with an incomplete or even empty file. Using a `with` statement makes the `close` automatic and impossible to get wrong, so you should usually do that.

Finally, `file2` and `File2` are not the same thing, so you will get a `NameError` if you define one name and then use the other.

---

Also, the long chain of `elif`s is clumsy, and very easy to get wrong (especially if you later have to fix or extend it). Try this:

```
numerals = ['ZERO', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 
            'SIX', 'SEVEN', 'EIGHT', 'NINE', 'TEN']
try:
    number = int(element)
    element = numerals[number]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
def numbers(fileName):
    numerals = ['ZERO', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 
                'SIX', 'SEVEN', 'EIGHT', 'NINE', 'TEN']
    fileName2 = "converted.txt"
    with open(fileName, "r") as file, open(fileName2, "w") as file2:
        for line in file:
            for element in line:
                try:
                    number = int(element)
                    element = numerals[number]
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                file2.write(element)
```

---

Obviously going character by character like this is not the most efficient way to read and write files. You should look at the other methods on string objects to see if there's something cleverer you can do. Or look at regular expressions, if you're willing to learn something a little trickier.

Comment: How would I include the other parts from the first file like "plus" and "is equal to" @abarnert

Comment: @user2958457: I don't understand the question. They're already included. Each element that's a digit, we swap in a numeral string in its place; each element that isn't a digit, we leave alone; then, either way, we write the element.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple find/replace:

```
def spell_numbers(in_file, out_file):
    s = open(in_file, 'r').read()
    s = s.replace('0', 'ZERO')
    s = s.replace('1', 'ONE')
    s = s.replace('2', 'TWO')
    s = s.replace('3', 'THREE')
    s = s.replace('4', 'FOUR')
    s = s.replace('5', 'FIVE')
    s = s.replace('6', 'SIX')
    s = s.replace('7', 'SEVEN')
    s = s.replace('8', 'EIGHT')
    s = s.replace('9', 'NINE')
    open(out_file, 'w').write(s)
```

If the file is too big to read into memory in it's entirety:

```
def spell_numbers(in_file, out_file, buf_size=1024):
    with open(in_file, 'r') as fin, open(out_file, 'w') as fout:
        while True:
            s = fin.read(buf_size)
            if not s: break
            s = s.replace('0', 'ZERO')
            s = s.replace('1', 'ONE')
            s = s.replace('2', 'TWO')
            s = s.replace('3', 'THREE')
            s = s.replace('4', 'FOUR')
            s = s.replace('5', 'FIVE')
            s = s.replace('6', 'SIX')
            s = s.replace('7', 'SEVEN')
            s = s.replace('8', 'EIGHT')
            s = s.replace('9', 'NINE')
            fout.write(s)
```

That will read in the file `buf_size` bytes at a time. 1024 means 1 KiB at a time, 1048576 means 1 MiB at a time.